# Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a subcategory of $\mathbf{B}$, s.t. $\forall$ $\mathbf{A}$-objects $A$, $A\xrightarrow{id}A$ is an $\mathbf{A}$-reflection

Tags: category-theory

I wish to prove that this implies that $\forall$ $\mathbf{A}$-objects $A$, any $\mathbf{A}$-reflection $A\xrightarrow{r_A}A^{*}$ is an $\mathbf{A}$-isomorphism.

What I have managed to show, without using the assumption above, is that there must be some $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $f$ s.t. $f\circ r_A = \mathrm{id}_A$ – this is by using the definition of an $\mathbf{A}$-reflection, and noting that $\mathrm{id}_A : A\to A$ is an $\mathbf{A}$-morphism, and therefore a $\mathbf{B}$-morphism. However, I'm struggling to find any $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $g$ s.t. $r_A \circ g = \mathrm{id}_{A^{*}}$, which would be necessary and sufficient to prove that $r_A$ is an $\mathbf{A}$-isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $r_A$ is a $\mathbf{A}$-morphism.  To prove this, we use the fact that $id_A$ is an $\mathbf{A}$-reflection for $A$: this implies that there exists an $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $g$ such that $g\circ id_A=r_A$.  But this just means that $r_A=g$ is an $\mathbf{A}$-morphism.

It now suffices to show that $r_A\circ f=id_{A^*}$, since then $r_A$ and $f$ are inverse $\mathbf{A}$-morphisms.  Now note that $(r_A\circ f)\circ r_A=r_A\circ(f\circ r_A)=r_A$ and $id_{A^*}\circ r_A=r_A$.  Thus $r_A\circ f$ and $id_{A^*}$ are both $\mathbf{A}$-morphisms $A^*\to A^*$ whose composition with $r_A$ is $r_A$.  By the uniqueness part of the definition of reflection, this means $r_A\circ f=id_{A^*}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm{id}_{A^*}\circ r_A= r_A$?

Comment: Oops, yes, I'll fix that.